# prove$((A\implies B) \wedge (C \implies D)) \implies ((A \wedge C) \implies (B \wedge D))$

Tags: logic

1 $((A\implies B) \wedge (C \implies D)) \implies ((A \wedge C) \implies (B \wedge D))$
2 $((A\implies C) \wedge (B \implies C)) \implies ((A \vee B) \implies C)$
can somebody give hints or answers of them ?

Comment: You need to use additional parentheses to make each of $1$ and $2$ understandable. There is no other way to disambiguate the parsing of the propositions. Also, please try to format the question as best you can, in order to make itreadable (separate 1 from 2), use parentheses, etc. Finally, please let us know what you've done so far. I, for one, can't guess what you are asking, and I can't help format what isn't clear to begin with. Nor can I guess what you do know.

Comment: I set the question in $\LaTeX$  Please see if I got it right.

Comment: You can use modus ponens or an equivalent form to $P \Rightarrow Q \equiv \neg P \vee Q$

Comment: What axioms and rules of inference can you use?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  For the first, assume $A \wedge C$ take it apart, prove $B$ and $D$, then $B \wedge D$.
For the second, assume $\lnot C$ and prove $\lnot (A \vee B)$

Answer (score 0):

As @Wishingwell's comment says, if you are allowed to use $P \implies Q \;\equiv\; \lnot P \lor Q$ then you can use this to expand both sides of each question, resulting in this:

1. $(\lnot A \lor B) \land (\lnot C \lor D) \;\implies\; \lnot (A \land C) \lor (B \land D)$
2. $(\lnot A \lor C) \land (\lnot B \lor C) \;\implies\; \lnot (A \lor B) \lor C$

Use De Morgan on the right hand sides, and remember that $\land$ distributes over $\lor$ and vice versa.